# SQL loop with $i and $_POST Values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to loop through a number of results from a form, but can't get it quite right.

```
  for ($i=1;$i<$total;i++)
    {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO MYSQL(value1,value2,value3) VALUES('{$i}','{$_POST['$iH']}', '{$_POST['$iA']}'");
    }
```

I want `$_POST['$iH']` to be the same as `$_POST['1H']`,`$_POST['2H']`, `$_POST['3H']` etc.

Comment: And where are you protecting yourself from SQL Injection?

Comment: I smell SQLi... again, what do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $total; $i++) { // <--- You had a typo here
   $sql  = "INSERT INTO MYSQL(value1,value2,value3) ";
   $sql .= "VALUES('{$i}','" . $_POST[$i . 'H'] . "', '" . $_POST[$i . 'A'] . "')";
   mysql_query($sql);
}
```

But, two big problems.

#### Multiple queries

Boy, what a waste! Dispatch one instead:

```
$rows = Array();
for ($i = 1; $i < $total; $i++) {
   $rows[] = "('{$i}','" . $_POST[$i . 'H'] . "', '" . $_POST[$i . 'A'] . "')";
}

$sql  = "INSERT INTO MYSQL(value1,value2,value3) VALUES('" . implode("','", $rows) . "')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

#### SQL injection

It continues to baffle me how, in 2011, people are still not getting this.

If you're going to insist upon using [the ancient `mysql` API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (not even [the OO version?!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) rather than [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), get into the habit of sanitising your inputs:

```
$rows = Array();
for ($i = 1; $i < $total; $i++) {
   $rows[] = "('{$i}'," . 
             "'" . mysql_escape_string($_POST[$i . 'H']) . "'," .
             "'" . mysql_escape_string($_POST[$i . 'A']) . "')";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MYSQL(value1,value2,value3) VALUES('" . implode("','", $rows) . "')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

OK, so without multi-query support in your API it's unlikely to cause you significant grief here, but it can do in authentication routines. Just get used to scripting properly in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for you help.To my defence, I've just started programming with PHP, but I appreciate all help I can get and if I can get it right from the start, even better!

Answer (score 1):

You really need to escape your post variables with mysql_real_escape_string()... you are seriously looking for trouble like that.

In answer to your question, I think you need to do something like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO MYSQL(value1,value2,value3) VALUES('{$i}', '" . $_POST[$i . 'H'] . "', '" . $_POST[$i.'A']. "'");
```

with the letters rubbing up against your variable, the php engine will assume they are part of the variable name; that variable name does not exist, so you will get some strange results.

Comment: No. You broke the interpolated variable in half.

Comment: hmm. yes I misformatted it.  That being said, the reasoning was sound; I'm not sure that deserved a downvote.

Comment: This is better now, except that you will have `{` and `}` characters in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes because your variable is being passed as a literal:

```
for ($i=1; $i<$total; $i++)
    {
     mysql_query('INSERT INTO MYSQL(value1,value2,value3) VALUES("' . $i . '","' . $_POST[$i . 'H'] . '", "' . $_POST[$i . 'A'] . '")');
    }
```

Comment: You didn't spot his typo, so you have one too!